# Can I be banned if most of my answers get negative scores?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, post-ban

I'm interested: can I be banned if most of my answers get a negative score? And if yes, what is limit before I get banned? I want to know an answer to this question because I have bad English, and I assume I will get downvotes for my answers. It is easy to write with good English when you write small text, but it's not my case, because I'm planning to write a lot of text to improve my English. Of course, I will give the most qualitative answers as best as I can, but most likely I will get downvoted because of my poor English.

Comment: Yes you can get banned and the exact rules are a secret. If you have issues with your english, then you could also think about asking one of your friends for proof reading before posting. But you generally shouldn't get downvotes if the post has grammar or spelling issues but is still overall correct, answers the question and has proper formatting. Grammar issues and typos can be fixed by the community.

Comment: you might want to read through the answer section here:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites. If poor English is your only issue, you should do fine.

Comment: Tip: the first-person pronoun, "I", is *always* capitalized.

Comment: Your publicly visible profile doesn't show answers. Maybe you have deleted answers. If you have deleted answers, keep in mind that deleted answers do count towards an answer ban. So, be careful when deleting your own answers.

Comment: As I see your username (french name) and country in your profile, depending on your skill, it can be an idea to participate a bit in https://french.stackexchange.com/ to get some point if you think you are near a ban, as you can use french there.

Comment: "It is easy to write with good English when you write small text, but it's not my case, because I'm planning to write a lot of text to improve my English."  - It sounds like you should focus on questions, where your knowledge is extensive in the subject matter, which should make it easier to provide quality answers in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact banning criterion thresholds are kept secret. But it's sure that you'll get banned if your answers keeps getting down-voted.

The ban is intended to stop people from negatively contributing to the community, which of course includes posting bad answers. The community's voting is the best indication of your posts' quality, so you'd better fix them before more are getting downvoted too much.

If you're really having trouble posting good English, you can ask a friend to help you correct and improve your post before submitting, or better yet, improve your English writing skills.